# Как принудительно перезаписать локальные файлы во время git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull

Как принудительно перезаписать локальные файлы во время [git](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) pull?

Имею следующий сценарий:

- Один из коллег вносит изменения в шаблоны веб-сайта, на котором мы работаем.
- Он добавляет несколько изображений в соответствующую директорию (но забывает добавить их в систему контроля версий).
- Затем он отправляет мне эти изображения по почте.
- Я добавляю изображения в систему контроля версий и отправляю их на Github вместе с другими изменениями.
- Сотрудник не может обновить свою версию проекта из Github, потому что git не переписывает его локальные файлы.

Ошибка выглядит так:

> error: Untracked working tree file 'public/images/icon.gif' would be overwritten by merge.

Как заставить Git перезаписать локальные файлы? Упомянутый сотрудник – дизайнер, и обычно все конфликты решаются мною вручную: я слежу, чтобы на сервере была самая последняя версия всех файлов, то есть мой коллега должен обновлять локальные файлы на своем компьютере.

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Force Git to overwrite local files on pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/)» [@Jakub Troszok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98046/).</sub>

Comment: *Я добавляю изображения в систему контроля версий* — плохое решение. blob-ы нежелательно помещать под управление системы контроля версий исходных **текстов**.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Буду крайне признателен, если вы оформите рекомендации в виде еще одного ответа или отдельного вопроса с ответом!

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Важно: Изменения, сделанные вами локально, будут потеряны. Как с опцией `--hard`, так и без нее, будут утеряны любые локальные коммиты, не отправленные на сервер. <sup>[*]</sup>

Если у вам есть *не* отслеживаемые локальные файлы (например, загруженные пользователями), они не будут затронуты.

---

Скорее всего, правильным решением в данном случае будет:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Или если вы находитесь в другой ветке:

```
git reset --hard origin/your_branch
```

#### Пояснение:

Команда `git fetch` загружает последнюю версию файлов из удаленного репозитория, не пытаясь что-либо объединить или синхронизировать (`merge` или `rebase`).

Затем `git reset` назначает главной веткой ту, которую вы только что обновили. Опция `--hard` изменяет все файлы в вашей рабочей ветке в соответствии с файлами в `origin/master`

---

<sup>[*]</sup>: Важно отметить, что поддерживать актуальность локальных изменений можно, если создать отдельную ветку от `master` перед тем, как выполнить `git reset`:

```
git checkout master
git branch new-branch-to-save-current-commits
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

После этого все старые версии будут храниться в `new-branch-to-save-current-commits`. Неподтвержденные изменения, тем не менее (даже индексированные), будут утеряны. Поэтому индексируйте и добавляйте в локальный репозиторий все, что вам может пригодиться.

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Force Git to overwrite local files on pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/564240)» [@RNA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489564/).</sub>

Comment: `... будут утеряны любые локальные коммиты, не отправленные на сервер` — ложь. Все исходные коммиты останутся и будут доступны через `git reflog`.

Comment: @Arhad ...пока их не съест `git gc` (который иногда запускается), потому что это "потеряшки", недоступные при обходе от тегов и веток. Мало гарантий, что они сохранятся.

Answer (score 5):

самый простой вариант («для дизайнера»):

1. удалить файлы, про которые команда *pull* написала упомянутое сообщение.
2. повторить команду *pull*.