# git pull в существующий каталог

Tags: git

на сервере есть сайт под CMS и GIT. Хочу локально развернуть репозиторий GIT на уже распакованный архив сайта. Проблема в том, что под git только часть директорий проекта, поэтому не могу просто сделать git clone в пустую папку.
Какими командами можно поднять git в уже существующей локальной директории и получить для уже существующих файлов, которые отслеживаются, свежие изменения?

Answer (score 1):

1. git init - инициализирует пустой репозиторий в текущей директории
2. git remote add origin [url] - добавит удаленный репозиторий
3. git add . - добавит все файлы в текущей директории в индекс
4. git fetch - скачает все изменения из удаленного репозитория
5. git checkout [branch] - переведет локальный репозиторий на нужную ветку(если это необходимо)

Comment: спасибо, первые 4-ре пункта сделаны, тут все понятно. Далее git status выводит наличие Untracked files.
git checkout [branch] выдает ошибку error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
и не очень понятно между какими ветками я должен переключаться в локальном репозитории

Comment: @Alexxander `git fetch` должен был скачать все изменения и создать в локальном репозитории те же ветки, что есть в удаленном. И после `git add .` не должно было остаться неотслеживаемых файлов. Может я неправильно понимаю условия задачи

Comment: прошу прощения за неточность, действительно нет  неотслеживаемых файлов после выполнения пунктов 1-4.
Остается вопрос что делает п.5 из Вашего списка и почему при вводе команды git checkout [branch] выдает ошибку error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
В чем смысл переключения между ветками?

Comment: @Alexxander это на случай, если вы работаете не в ветке по умолчанию, потому что у меня обычно есть несколько веток типа "release", "dev", etc и, соответственно, ветка по умолчанию в репозитории, например, dev, а на сервере логично разворачивать release. Попробуйте сделать из текущего состояния git pull или git merge (смержит то, что скачано из удаленного репозитория и то, что лежит сейчас в локальном)

Comment: в текущем состоянии `git pull` приводит к сообщению 
`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting`.    
Команда `$ git merge` приводит к сообщению:
`fatal: No remote for the current branch.`

Я так понимаю, что надо сейчас слить локальные файлы и полученные из центрального репозитория на сервере. При этом безусловный приоритет должен быть у файлов из удаленного репозитория. Ветка везде пока одна - `master`.

Comment: @Alexxander команды `git stash` и `git stash apply` спрячут изменения и вернут их. После stash можно сделать pull. Это если надо сохранить локальные изменения. Чтобы перезаписать используйте git pull -f

Comment: пробовал `git stash` и `git pull -f` - ошибки. Выполнял эти команды после `git init` и `git remote add origin [url]`. Пробовал их выполнять после команд `git add . ` и `git fetch`. 
есть удаленный боевой репо с единственной веткой master. Локально развернул архив сайта (почти как боевой по составу). Делаю локально `git init` и `git remote add origin [url]`. Это все понятно и работает. Теперь хочу закачать свежие изменения на локальный репо. Сразу писать `git pull -f` не выходит, ошибки. Если не затруднит, объясните пожалуйста по шагам какие дальше команды и какой смысл каждой. Спасибо!

Comment: @Alexxander честно говоря нет больше идей, могу лишь посоветовать git-scm.com - там хорошо описаны все возможности гита, к тому же на русском. Возможно поможет ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515435/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-git-pull

Comment: спасибо, значит пока буду читать заново git-scm, может позже придет озарение